# How to handle client-sessions in socket.io

Tags: node.js, session, socket.io

I use client-sessions, not the express sessions. How could I get session data. Session stores on the client, not on a server.
I use client-session module https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the right answer, to get session from cookie, first you should parse the cookie

```
handshakeData.cookie = cookie.parse(handshakeData.headers.cookie);
```

Than you have to decode the cookie, I used the original function from client-session module

```
var clientSessions = require('./node_modules/client-sessions/lib/client-sessions')

    var opts = { 
      cookieName: 'yourSessionName'
      , secret: 'secret'
    }
    var decoded = clientSessions.util.decode(opts, handshakeData.cookie['yourSessionName'])
```

**decoded** object holds your session data

Comment: Can you provide some link or documentation for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the session data on the client, you could just use the module's built-in features. If you need it on the server, then you could get the information on client-side and then emit it with socket.io, something like socket.emit('sendSocketData', dataToSend);